# Problema com select dinamico para mostrar menu dropdown para usuário

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou construindo a camada de visualização para os clientes de um sistema em minha base de dados tenho duas tabelas com relacionamentos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e tenho um método para retornar os resultados dessas tabelas:

```
 public function dropDownCategoria() {
    $consulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("SELECT categoria_pagina.id_categoria_pagina as cat_id, categoria_pagina.nome as c_nome,
    pagina.id_pagina as p_id, pagina.tema, pagina.data, pagina.id_categoria_pagina,
    descricao_pagina.id_descricao_pagina, descricao_pagina.sub_titulo, descricao_pagina.texto_da_pagina, descricao_pagina.id_pagina as d_Id_pag,
    imagem.id_imagem, imagem.nome as img_nome, imagem.tipo, imagem.tamanho, imagem.id_pagina as img_id_pagina,
    descricao_imagem.id_descricao_imagem, descricao_imagem.titulo, descricao_imagem.texto_da_imagem, descricao_imagem.id_imagem
    FROM categoria_pagina
    left JOIN pagina ON (pagina.id_categoria_pagina = categoria_pagina.id_categoria_pagina)
    left JOIN descricao_pagina ON (descricao_pagina.id_pagina = pagina.id_pagina)
    left JOIN imagem ON(imagem.id_pagina = pagina.id_pagina)
    left JOIN descricao_imagem ON(descricao_imagem.id_imagem = imagem.id_imagem)
    group by c_nome");
    $consulta->execute();
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="index.php?id_categoria='.$linha->id_categoria_pagina.'" class="dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown">' . $linha->c_nome . '<b class="caret"></b></a>';

        $novaConsulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("Select * from pagina where id_categoria_pagina=:'$linha->p_id'");
        $novaConsulta->execute();
        while ($novaLinha = $novaConsulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            echo'<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php?pagina=' . $novaLinha->id_pagina . '">';
        echo $novaLinha->tema;
        echo '</a></li></ul></li>';
        }



    }
}
```

ele se trata de um dropDown:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o problema é que não está trazendo os resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parecer a falta do bind na consulta e também as aspas sobrando, que estão causando um erro.

```
    $novaConsulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("
    Select * from pagina where id_categoria_pagina=:'$linha->p_id'");
                                                   ^^            ^ 
    caracteres inválidos---------------------------||------------|

    $novaConsulta->execute();
    while ($novaLinha = $novaConsulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
```

Acredito que a sua intenção era fazer dessa forma:

```
    $novaConsulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("
    Select * from pagina where id_categoria_pagina = :id");
    $novaConsulta->execute(array(':id' => $linha->p_id));
```

Comment: muito obrigado por sua resposta.